# Laravel символьная ссылка на папку с фото на хостинге

Tags: laravel

На локальном ПК ссылка выглядит так

> http://psiholog.local/storage/uploads/rGyMd8hnz6CybUfbqGP4FG6UIzsoQ0mJjhUTSUTu.jpeg

Перенес на хостинг, фото не грузит, методом научного тыка нашел как хранятся фото

> http://test.n985572n.beget.tech/storage/app/public/uploads/z0SxISj9yniZuomDoZBn51S3PLGba8MaXnDEznR0.jpeg

Как сделать ссылки одинаковыми?

На пк запускал команду `php artisan storage:link`
На хостинге просто создал символьную ссылку на папку

Comment: а ссылку вы эту как генерируете?

Comment: <pre>$path=$request->file('image')->store('uploads', 'public');   <code>

'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',